# Ciclo FOR para agregar fechas no existes

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente ciclo for para recorer de 0 a 24 horas de un dato convertido a string en el cual los elementos que no existen me los agregue pero tambien quiero hacerlo con las fechas, el problema no es pasar los datos a string sino que identificar que dia mes y año debe tener en un rango de tiempo.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii <= 24; ii++)
        {
            DataRow[] dr = rs.Tables[0].Select("HOURS = " + (ii < 10 ? "0" : "") + ii.ToString());
            if (dr.Length == 0)
            {
                DataRow drnew = rs.Tables[0].NewRow();
                rs.Tables[0].Rows.Add((ii < 10 ? "0" : "") + ii.ToString() + ":00:00");
            }
        }
```

Comment: podrías almacenar los valore día, mes y año como fecha, ordenando los registros por este valor y haciendo un distinct

Answer (score 2):

Según entiendo, vos querés recorrer desde una fecha a hasta una fecha b día por día, sin tener que llamar 3 'for's y andar checkeando días del mes, etc.

Interesantemente, esto funciona:

```
DateTime fechaInicial = //Fecha Inicio
DateTime fechaFinal = //Fecha Fin

for (DateTime d = fechaInicial; d <= fechaFinal; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
    //Hacer algo con la fecha
}
```